# how to find an almost increasing sequence Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have had an algorithm problem below:

> "Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.
>
> Example
>
> For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
>   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;
>
> There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.
>
> For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
>   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.
>
> You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3]."

My code (for Javascript) was:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
var count =0;

for (i =0 ; i<sequence.length-1 ; i++){
if (sequence[i+1]<=sequence[i]){
    count++;
   }
 }
return count <2;
}
```

However if in the case of sequence =[1,2,3,4,3,4,5]
My code will be wrong;

Please explain to me an algorithm that can be used to solve this problem.
And also please explain in step by step so that I can understand.

Sorry for not being clear as it is my first question here.

Comment: you may add some code you tried.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for this is my first question . I have already added my code please have a look again

Comment: Dear all please also help me to point out what I should do to improve my question for now and in the future as it is my first question

Comment: Sorry but just curious, didn't my answer below work as expected?

Comment: Dear @Rüzgar it mostly work however if the case is [1,1] it won't t. It return false while it should be true . Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: :) Sorry @JimmyYouhei, the code would have worked perfect as expected, if i accidentally hadn't used `sequence` instead of `mainSequence`. I edited my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    var exists = false; // Assume the sequence returns false by default
    var mainSequence = sequence.slice(); // Clone sequence so that we can use it again
    m_seq: // The name of the first loop, so that we can exit from it
    for (var i = 0; i < mainSequence.length; i++) { // Loop through the array 
        sequence.splice(i,1); // Remove an item from the array
        s_seq: // The name of the loop, so that we can exit from it
        for (var j = 0; j < mainSequence.length-1; j++) { // Loop through sliced array, to find an increasing sequence
            if (sequence[j+1] <= sequence[j]) { // Check if next is smaller
                exists = false; // if so define false
                break s_seq; // exit from the loop
            }
            exists = true; // if the loop has not been interrupted, return true
        }
        sequence = mainSequence.slice(); // Reassign the main sequence to be used again.
        //console.log('s',mainSequence);
        if (exists) {break m_seq;} // İf condition is met, why bother to stay in the loop???
    }
        return exists;
}

var testing = [1,2,3,4,3,4,5];
var testingAgain = [1,2,3,4,3,7,9];
var testingFinal = [1,1];
// almostIncreasingSequence(testing);
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence(testing));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence(testingAgain));
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence(testingFinal));
```